# Is There ANY Sense in SQL Data Type VARCHAR(1)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, types

I've bumped into a lot of VARCHAR(1) fields in a database I've recently had to work with.  I rolled my eyes: obviously the designer didn't have a clue.  But maybe I'm the one who needs to learn something.  Is there any conceivable reason to use a VARCHAR(1) data type rather than CHAR(1)?  I would think that the RDMS would convert the one to the other automatically.

The database is MS SQL 2K5, but evolved from Access back in the day.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is sense to it.

- Easier for it to be definable in the language.  It is consistent and easier to define varchar to allow 1-8000 than to say it needs to be 2+ or 3+ to 8000.
- The VARying CHARacter aspect of VARCHAR(1) is exactly that. It may not be optimal for storage but conveys a specific meaning, that the data is either 1 char (classroom code) or blank (outside activity) instead of NULL (unknown/not-yet-classified).

Storage plays very little part in this - looking at a database schema for CHAR(1), you would almost expect that it must always have a 1 char value, such as credit cards must have 16 digits.  That is simply not the case with some data where it can be one or optionally none.

There are also differences to using VARCHAR(1) vs CHAR(1)+NULL combination for those who say tri-state [ 1-char | 0-char | NULL ] is completely useless.  It allows for SQL statements like:

```
select activity + '-' + classroom
from  ...
```

which would otherwise be more difficult if you use char(1)+NULL, which can convey the same information but has subtle differences.

Comment: I can see that there'd be no real reason for the implementation to *prohibit* VARCHAR(1), but I'm asking if there would be any design benefit.  Regarding your second point, just to clarify, you're pointing out that VARCHAR(1) can be an empty string, but CHAR(1) cannot?  I can see that; an obscure reason to choose VARCHAR(1) over CHAR(1), but conceivably a valid one.

Comment: "•Easier for it to be definable in the language." - can you elborate?

Comment: The subtlety plays up in certain edge cases, `CASE WHEN ' ' = ''` actually evals to TRUE, i.e. single-space = no-space but you need to be very aware of such things. Simply disregarding a datatype off-hand is not really very smart. The text after the two points illustrate a more solid example, which I have seen in real life (just not those columns specifically).

Comment: @Mitch - I can't find the ANSI specs, but wikipedia/wiki/SQL has this `CHARACTER VARYING(n) or VARCHAR(n) — variable-width string with a maximum size of n characters`. Aside from the fact that it is useful to allow varchar(1), it is easier than for the text to say `CHARACTER VARYING(n) or VARCHAR(n) — variable-width string with a maximum size of n characters, where n >= 2` hypothetically assuming that we do want to prevent varchar(1).

Comment: Well, from an Oracle perspective Tom Kite disagrees! I would never use varchar(1). Char(1) to me implies a column will contain 1 and exactly one character. I would question a schema design that has varchar(1) OR char(1) nullable.

Comment: @Mitch - I think you mean Tom `Kyte`. What does it matter what he thinks? This still works in oracle `create table T (X varchar(1));` You and I are two people and we already have 2 opinions, you make yours based on your opinion of not using them and not having seen them in real use. That's what S.O. is here for, to put questions to the masses who may have experience where others don't.

Comment: @cyberkiwi : Yes it's Tom Kyte. You are saying ignore the wisdom of an experienced professional whose credentials are impeccable? That's not what I do.

Comment: @Mitch - for each professional there are various others who may or may not disagree. Nothing personal, but it's like I don't agree with everything you say just because you are an MS MVP. There are other MS MVPs who hold different opinions across different subjects. `Nobody` is right `all` the time.

Comment: @Mitch - If Kyte felt so strongly about it, you'd think `create table T (X varchar(1));` would raise an error?

Comment: *that the data is either 1 char (classroom code) or blank (outside activity)*. Assuming that "blank" does not refer to null, this justification implies the use of a zero length string which is its own dubious design choice and would also violate the least astonishment rule. Use of `Coalesce` with a null and values with lengths greater than zero is more explicit and more flexible.

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK, No.

a `VARCHAR(1)` requires 3 bytes storage (The storage size is the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).

a `CHAR(1)` requires 1 byte.

From a storage perspective: A rule of thumb is, if it's less than or equal to 5 chars, consider using a fixed length char column.

A reason to avoid varchar(1) (aside from the fact they they convey poor design reasoning, IMO) is when using Linq2SQL: [LINQ to SQL and varchar(1) fields](http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/07/17/linq-to-sql-and-varchar-1-fields.aspx)

Comment: Not a good rule of thumb. The problem with fixed-length 4 vs varchar(4) is that `char(4) + '-x'` has unwanted spaces. Yes you can trim, but that's adding complexity that is not required simply using varchar(4).

Comment: @cyberkiwi : I'm aware of that. I'm talking about from a storage perspective.

Comment: I didn't pick that the question was asking about `storage` specifically. But your edit makes it more clear about your answer scope.

Comment: @Mitch - that Linq2SQL issue is a `bug`. The `bug` once fixed renders the point invalid, and is `extremely` localised to VS2008. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/ac91e587-6e91-454c-9fa2-bab20b7a258c, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqtosql/thread/e8082fc1-a5be-47bf-9b06-cd1bde19bea0

Comment: @cyberkiwi : I know its a bug; that's why I mentioned it!

Comment: @Mitch You could qualify it as a bug rather than leaving the impression that it is not supposed to work with LINQ. From reading the text without investigating it, I would not have known it is `not` by-design

Comment: Thanks, Mitch, for reminding us why CHAR(1) is generally superior.  Cyberkiwi pointed out how a VARCHAR(1) can in fact do one thing a CHAR(1) cannot, which answered my question, but your post is the real takeaway: VARCHAR(1) is almost always simply a waste of space.

Comment: IMO, this the right answer. `Varchar(1)` violates the least astonishment rule, gains nothing and does have a cost (however slight) in storing an extra bit to indicate the number of characters actually in use. I cannot think of any situation where it would be a logical design choice.

Comment: @Thomas - I can. Altering fixed length datatypes can be much more work compared to variable length ones.

Comment: @MartinSmith - That claim strikes me as counter-intuitive. Do you have evidence to support it? I'm skeptical that changing say a `varchar(1)` to a `varchar(2)` will incur any more cost than changing a `char(1)` to a `char(2)`.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I suppose there is extra work in adding padding but now the question is "how much extra"? Of course, we are both ignoring the fact that fundamentally altering the nature of a column should itself be an infrequent event and thus its cost in effecting the change is mostly irrelevant in the grander scheme of things.

Comment: @Thomas - "How much extra?" If the column is part of the clustered PK then potentially the cost of rebuilding the whole table and all non clustered indexes. It won't even let you alter the column definition without dropping the PK first. In other parts of software engineering it is well understood that the only certainty is change.

Comment: @MartinSmith - However, it is also true that in parts of software engineering, the probability of specific types of changes are not equal and those probabilities change over time. Dropping the PK in a column that is `char(1)` will not be expensive to that table. It can't be because the number of unique values it can contain is limited. However, dropping the foreign key constraints to that table with a `char(1)` PK could be expensive and if I'm not mistaken, you would have to do that whether you are using `char` or `varchar`.

Comment: @Thomas - Please see the example I have added to my answer. I am sure you will agree that the `varchar` version does much less work. Dropping and recreating FK constraints means that they need to be verified again when re-added but doesn't involve any writes.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I'll concede that under a narrow set of circumstances, altering a `varchar(1)` instead of a `char(1)` will finish in a time that might make a meaningful difference even though it would require multiple millions of rows. However, the overwhelming majority of the time, the time difference will be irrelevant because of the infrequency with which this type of operation is performed. The motivation to use `varchar(1)` because "some day" you might have to expand it and that operation will be slightly faster is dubious. Clarity of intent should win over premature optimization.

Comment: @Thomas - If it is potentially varying but currently limited to 1 character then `varchar(1)` states the intent clearer than `char(1)` IMO.

Answer (score 6):

A `varchar(1)` can store a zero length ("empty") string. A `char(1)` can't as it will get padded out to a single space. If this distinction is important to you you may favour the `varchar`.

Apart from that, one use case for this may be if the designer wants to allow for the possibility that a greater number of characters may be required in the future.

Altering a fixed length datatype from `char(1)` to `char(2)` means that all the table rows need to be updated and any indexes or constraints that access this column dropped first.

Making these changes to a large table in production can be an extremely time consuming operation that requires down time.

Altering a column from `varchar(1)` to `varchar(2)` is much easier as it is a metadata only change (FK constraints that reference the column will need to be dropped and recreated but no need to rebuild the indexes or update the data pages).

Moreover the 2 bytes per row saving might not always materialize anyway. If the row definition is already quite long this won't always affect the number of rows that can fit on a data page. Another case would be if using the compression feature in Enterprise Edition the way the data is stored is entirely different than that mentioned in Mitch's answer in any event. Both `varchar(1)` and `char(1)` would end up stored the same way in the short data region.

@Thomas - e.g. try this table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE T2
(
Code VARCHAR(1),
Foo datetime2,
Bar int,
Filler CHAR(4000),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Code, Foo, Bar)
)

INSERT INTO T2
SELECT TOP 100000 'A', 
                  GETDATE(), 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)),
                  NULL
FROM master..spt_values v1,  master..spt_values v2

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T2_Foo ON T2(Foo) INCLUDE (Filler);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T2_Bar ON T2(Bar) INCLUDE (Filler);
```

For a `varchar` it is trivial to change the column definition from `varchar(1)` to `varchar(2)`. This is a metadata only change.

```
ALTER TABLE T2 ALTER COLUMN Code VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
```

If the change is from `char(1)` to `char(2)` the following steps must happen.

1. Drop the PK from the table. This converts the table into a heap and means all non clustered indexes need to be updated with the RID rather than the clustered index key.
2. Alter the column definition. This means all rows are updated in the table so that  `Code` now is stored as `char(2)`.
3. Add back the clustered PK constraint. As well as rebuilding the CI itself this means all non clustered indexes need to be updated again with the CI key as a row pointer rather than the RID.